# MCMC algorithm going wrong

Tags: self-study, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Given this integral

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \chi_{[1,2]}(x)\Gamma(C,x)\left|\cos(R x)\right| \, dx
\end{equation}

where $\chi_{[1,2]}=\begin{cases}1, & x \in [1,2] \\ 0, & x\not \in [1,2]\end{cases}$

I need to estimate its value using MCMC with Metropolis algorithm and acceptance.

I wrote the sampler as it follows:

```py
def sampler(N):
    step=1
    old=1.5
    i=0
    points=[]   
    while i<N:
        points.append(old)
        ant=func(old)
        inov=norm.rvs(0,step)
        new=old+inov
        prox=func(new)
        alphah=min(1,prox/ant)
        if alphah>np.random.uniform():
            old=new
        i+=1
    points.append(old)
    return points
```

`sampler(N)` generates $N$ points by using the Metropolis Algorithm with N(0,step) as kernel and starting in 1.5.

The function `func(x)` evaluates $\chi_{[1,2]}(x)\Gamma(C,x)\left|\cos(R x) \right|$.

After generating $N$ points $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_N$ the estimative is
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \chi_{[1,2]}(x_i)\Gamma(C,x_i) \left|\cos(R x_i)\right|
\end{equation}

The problem is that doing like that I find approximately 0.28 while I need to find 0.26

My algorithm is wrong? Or there is something that I'm not seeing?

EDIT: Implementation of `func` and the Monte Carlo algorithm `mc`

```
def func(x):
    c=1.398031095
    d=1.9298378
    if x<=2 and x>=1:
        return gamma.pdf(c,x)*abs(np.cos(d*x))
    return 0

def mc(N):
    points=sampler(N)
    i=0
    g=0
    while i <N:
        g+=func(points[i])
        i+=1
    return g/N
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the implemention of `func`, too. Right now I can't find anything wrong with this. Perhaps you're not running it for long enough

Comment: I will post the implemention of ```func``` and  monte carlo

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: I found the error, I wrote on ```func``` gamma.pdf(c,x). But the correct function is gamma.pdf(x,c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main confusion is that you appear to not be correctly identifying the difference between the functional and the target distribution. I would say your target distribution appears to be a simple uniform distribution, while the functional is the fancy guy. Confusingly, your functional involves a gamma density.

MCMC gives you an estimate of an expectation. Your expectation is this:

$$
\int_0^\infty \chi_{[1,2]}(x)\Gamma(C,x)\left|\cos(R x)\right| \, dx = E_X[h(x)]
$$
where $h(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(c)}x^{c-1}e^{-x} \left|\cos(R x)\right|$ is the function that your `func` evaluates, and $X \sim \text{Uniform}(1,2]$. $h$ is the functional, and $\text{Uniform}(1,2]$ is the target distribution.

Metropolis-Hastings wouldn't be my first choice for this problem, but you seem to be using random walk Metropolis-Hastings. I think this because you are proposing samples like this:
$$
X^*\mid X_{t-1} \sim \text{Normal}(X_{t-1}, 1).
$$
You call $X^*$ `new`, and $1$ `step` (this name confuses me, but that's not that important).

You can write your target distribution as $\pi(x) = \chi_{[1,2]}(x)$, and this makes your acceptance ratio
$$
a(x_{t-1},x^*) = \min(1, \pi(x^*)/\pi(x_{t-1})).
$$
Note that you are incorrectly calculating this with `min(1,prox/ant)`. You are using the $h$ function here, when you shouldn't be (if you're targeting this uniform distribution). Instead, use this code (yours with minimal changes)

```
from scipy.stats import gamma,norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def sampler(N):
    step=1
    old=1.5
    i=0
    points=[]   
    while i<N:
        points.append(old)
        ant= 1 if 1 < old <= 2 else 0
        inov=norm.rvs(0,step)
        new=old+inov
        prox = 1 if 1 < new <= 2 else 0 
        alphah=min(1,prox/ant)

        if alphah>np.random.uniform():
            old=new
        i+=1
    points.append(old)
    return points
```

Your `mc` function appears to be correct. It is calculating 
$$
N^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} h(x_t)
$$
where $x_t$ are all your samples (which you are calling `points`).

Finally, yes, your answer is valid as well. You are likely reversing the argument order in the `gamma.pdf` function.

Comment: How do you know that the target distribution is the Uniform(1,2) ?

Comment: It doesn’t have to be. It could also be a gamma distribution. In that case the functional would only be the trigonometric part and the indicator function multiplied together. If you decided to go this route, you would have to change the code in different ways.

Comment: But taking the gamma as target distribution the integral must be the same right?

Comment: As long as you change the functional accordingly.

Comment: Known that $g \propto \chi_{[1,2]}h(x) $ the integral of g is calculated the way I calculated in my post right? And even knowing this proportionality the target function can be the uniform?

Comment: Targeting the uniform does not make sense since you can easily sample from it. I think you should target the function proportional to gamma times cosine

Comment: @Giiovanna perhaps you mean that one should just use regular Monte Carlo. I agree with that; this is what I was alluding to when I said "Metropolis-Hastings wouldn't be my first choice for this problem." In any event, this is a self-study question, so I figured my role was to help with the understanding, not to advise on superior methods. Also note that targeting that would require you to find the normalizing constant of that unnormalized distribution.

Comment: @Taylor why would you have to find the normalizing constant? If $g(x) = A \Gamma(C,x)|cos(Rx)|$ and $h(x) = \chi[1,2](x)$, then the Metropolis $\alpha$ does not depends on $A$ nor the MC integral estimative $1/N \sum h(x) $. What am I not seeing?

Comment: @Giiovanna you do not need normalizing constants to evaluate the acceptance ratio in the algorithm, but once you have that running, you still have samples from a normalized $g(x)$. If you take sample averages, then you will be estimating an expectation with respect to this normalized distribution, which means you will be estimating a scaled version of what OP is after. If you want to discuss this further, we should probably start do that somewhere else in order to avoid making the comment section too long.

Comment: @Taylor the question is stated as following: Calculate $I = \int h(x) g(x) dx$ via MCMC where $h(x) = \chi[1,2] (x)$ and $g(x) \propto \Gamma(C,x) |cos(Rx)|$. it seems like the intention is to sample from $g$, which is difficult since we don't know it's normalizing constant. Also, one of the questions is why we don't have to know it's constant, and I think is due the cancelation in $alpha$ formula.

Comment: @Taylor alright. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work for you. My question is why do you have `new=old+inov` in your sampler? I replaced that with `new=inov`. Also, you should expect to see some deviations. I didn't really dig into this problem much but  I do not think there is much of a difference between 0.26 and 0.28. Is it given that 0.26 is the target value (mean) for this distribution?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma, norm


def func(x):
    c=1.398031095
    d=1.9298378
    if x<=2 and x>=1:
        return gamma.pdf(c,x)*abs(np.cos(d*x))
    return 0

def mc(N):
    points=sampler(N)
    i=0
    g=0
    while i <N:
        g+=func(points[i])
        i+=1
    return g/N




def sampler(N):
    step=1
    old=1.5
    i=0
    points=[]   
    while i<N:
        points.append(old)
        ant=func(old)
        inov=norm.rvs(0,step)
        new= inov #old+inov
        prox=func(new)
        alphah=min(1,prox/ant)
        if alphah>np.random.uniform():
            old=new
        i+=1
    points.append(old)
    return points

out = sampler(10000)
out = np.array(out)

results = np.array(list(map(func, out)))
print(np.mean(results))
```

Comment: Yes it is given that we should aim for 0.26

Comment: Doing what you did doesn't chance the markov process?